# Getting the cumsum of vector with the first element counting itself as well

Tags: matlab, vector, cumsum

I would like to get the `cumsum` of an vector, but need the first element of the vector to count itself as well. An example:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5]
```

and the result needs to look as follow:

```
2 3 6 10 15
```

Comment: `b=cumsum(a);
b(1)=b(1)+a(1)`?

Comment: Hi Daniel, Sorry you all posted so quickly an answer I actually missed yours.  Thank you for the answer as well.  Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you already know about the `cumsum` function so, have you not tried?:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5];
s = cumsum(a);
s(1) = s(1)+a(1)
```

which returns

```
s =

     2     3     6    10    15
```

Comment: Dear Sir, thank you very much for your help.  I am in aww of how quickly I was helped, this is greatly appreciated.  Your answer hits the nail on the head.  I indeed know of the cumsum but still have a lot to learn.  I have only started the last 2 weeks working with Matlab, intensely learning, working and breaking my head using it,and still have a lot to learn but I definitely would like to master it.  This forum is one of the best things that has happened to me.  Kind Regards

Comment: @Crysthius: Thank you and welcome to SO. I hope that you contribute as well as ask questions. Also, please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) regarding the use of comments on this site. We try to stick to the matter at hand with both questions and comments here, rather than put too much unrelated stuff (that's also why I edited your question)

Comment: Thank you for the reminder and thank you for editing my question.  I will do my best in answering where I can. All of the best. Kind Regards